# find specific word and read after that word in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, program-slicing

so i am very very new to python. 
need some basic help.

my logic is to find words in text file.

```
party A %aapple 1
Party B %bat 2
Party C c 3
```

i need to find all the words starts from %.

my code is

```
 searchfile = open("text.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
 for char in line:
if "%" in char:
    print char      

searchfile.close()
```

but the output is only the % character. I need the putput to be %apple and %bat

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading the file properly.

```
searchfile = open("text.txt", "r")

lines = [line.strip() for line in searchfile.readlines()]
for line in lines:
    for word in line.split(" "):
        if word.startswith("%"):
            print word

searchfile.close()
```

You should also explore regex to solve this as well.

Comment: this is just printing the start letter. i need the whole word. like apple. not just an A

Comment: No it is not.  What is your input. I am updating the answer to print the word including the % right now it apple , bat

Comment: I tested the script and it is working properly. But you are opening ```test.txt``` but @user3296651 wanted to open ```text.txt```.

Comment: its working now. thanks. can you share some link for basic python tutorial?

Comment: https://www.udacity.com/course/programming-foundations-with-python--ud036

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of exemplification, I'm following up on Bipul Jain's reccomendation of showing how this can be done with regex:

```
import re

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()

re.findall(r'%\w+', file)
```

results:

```
['%apple', '%bat']
```